# Need steps for a basic python loop question

Tags: python, loops

I am a complete noob to programming so excuse the ignorance. I am taking a MOOC and can't for the life of me figure out what steps to take to solve this problem:

Assume s is a string of lower case characters.

Write a program that prints the number of times the string 'bob' occurs in s. For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl', then your program should print

Number of times bob occurs is: 2

OK. I know that a for loop is necessary. I think it should start with:

```
x=bob
count=0
for count in range(s):
>if
```

Here I am not sure how to retrieve the specific word 'bob' from the index, and I know I need to enter count+=1 but am not sure where. Could someone please help me? I am sure I could solve this on myself but I am getting frustrated after a few hours!

Comment: You`ll need `range(len(s))` instead of `range(s)`, since `s` is not an integer. Then, use `x == s[count : count+len(x)]`.

Comment: Aha! I was thinking I might have to convert the str into int. Thanks boss.

Comment: Would I need to nest my if statements after that? I am still uncertain how to begin these next if statements.

Comment: You don't need to nest any if statements. Think of it this way. When you are looking at string `s`, how do you know that the word in `x` has started? Now that you know it's started, how do you know it has ended?

Comment: I'm seriously at a standstill. Do I need to redefine x now? I am not sure how to isolate the value of an individual letter. Do I need to use an if statement at all? Here is what I have now: ```for x in range(len(s)):
    >x==s[count:count+lensx)]```

Comment: Any help to walk me through would really be appreciated. I am combing through explanations of iterations and branching programs but I still can't get through this mental block.

Answer (score 2):

```
# our input variables:
term = 'bob'
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

# where I store count of found search term:
count = 0

# we are going from 0 to length of input string:
for i in range(len(s)):

    # compare the slice from <current index> to <current index + length of search term> to search term
    if s[i:i+len(term)] == term:
        # it there's match, increase the count
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Prints:

```
2
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is my solution:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl' 
x = 'bob'
count = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if x == s[i : i + len(x)]:
        count+= 1
print(count)
```

Few things to note. First of all your `for` statement had a couple errors, where you are using the variable `count` before the statement but also creating a new variable `count` in the for statement, and so I replaced it in the statement with the variable name `i` so that it would not override your first `count` variable. Secondly, it would need to be `range(len(s))` as `s` is a string and you will want to iterate up to it's length.

Finally to explain the `if x == s[i : i + len(x)]:` part, this is to see if X is the same as the i'th position in S, along with the next 2 letters in S, because the length of X ('bob') is 3, so you'll need to be looking at every `len(x)` or three letters in the `s` string.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this, I am pretty sure someone can optimise the code, I just tried a quick one. It works so far.

```
keyword = "bob"
text = "azcbobobegghakl"
n = len(keyword)
temp = ""
counter = 0
for x in (text):
    temp += x
    if len(temp)%(n+1) == 0:
        temp = temp[1::]
        if keyword in temp:
            counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work but it is somehow missing just one 'bob' in a few instances for example: 'bobobobobobobobobobob' 10 was expected. I will use your answer as I could not for the life of me wrap my head around how to go about this problem. Any tips or resources for practicing and learning more about these? Most guides did not provide more info than the lecture.

Comment: go for it, I didnt realise that, yes is true, it is missing the first bob. I think HackerRank.com is a great place to practice code. I use it from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion to complete the answers already given.

You probably could start by checking if the string you are looking for, `'bob'`, exists in the string to be searched, `s`, for example:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
if 'bob' in s:
    # your searching algotithm
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also work

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl' 
x = 'bob'
count = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i:].startswith(x):
            count += 1
```